# BackgroundTask UWP Windows 10 TimeTriggeredTask Example registered but never fires up

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I am testing the Background Example with the Scenario4 and it never calls to Run, I am following the steps and that's what I see:

1.- After calling

```
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

The task has Trigger = null

Does it should be the trigger specified before in

```
builder.SetTrigger(trigger); ?
```

2.- In theory when I register a background task, it should appear in here EventViewer - BackgroundTaskInfrastructure but it doesn't, should appear here?

3.- To try to debug I Debug Location - Suspend the App but after more than 15 minutes it never arrives, should be simple as suspend and wait?

Also I added inside Run a notification:

```
var toastXML = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
var toastTextElements = toastXML.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements.First().AppendChild(toastXML.CreateTextNode("Hello World:"));
var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(toastXML);
toastNotification.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
```

But it never appears. So is BackgroundTask with TimeTrigger working?

Comment: I have the same problem, but have not find a solution yet.

Comment: Same problem, TimeTrigger never fires the BackgroundTask on Desktop, it does however work perfectly on Phone.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have an await call in the Run method of the BackgroundTask. After watching the video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-RTM/Background-Execution I learn that I have to call to:

```
 var cost = BackgroundWorkCost.CurrentBackgroundWorkCost;
```

And get the

```
 var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
```

And finally when my calls finish call to:

```
 deferral.Complete();
```

With that now it calls always my task always finish, the only issue and I think that it is not allowed is that I cannot call to:

```
  Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(favorite.Uri, UriKind.Absolute));
```

might be the launcher is not allowed but the toast is now showed every 15 minutes.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar No, the smallest TimeTrigger you can have is 15 minutes