# UWP Background Task does not work with Timetrigger but works with TimeZoneChange

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I have app which implements in-process backgroundTask. The code below works.

```
            await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            builder.Name = TaskName;
            builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false));
            BackgroundTaskRegistration registration = builder.Register();
            registration.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
```

The code below does not work.

```
            await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            builder.Name = TaskName;
            builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
            BackgroundTaskRegistration registration = builder.Register();
            registration.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
```

There is no error and no crashing. The task does not get triggered by the time trigger. The systemTrigger works fine. Is there something that I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526948/timetrigger-not-firing-backgroundtask-uwp

Comment: Could you show more detail about how did you debug the `TimeTrigger`?